# Singleton implementation in Go

Tags: go, casting, thread-safety, singleton

I have a struct:

```
type cache struct {
    cap     int
    ttl     time.Duration
    items   map[interface{}]*entry
    heap    *ttlHeap
    lock    sync.RWMutex
    NoReset bool
}
```

Interface implemented by it:

```
type Cache interface {
    Set(key, value interface{}) bool
    Get(key interface{}) (interface{}, bool)
    Keys() []interface{}
    Len() int
    Cap() int
    Purge()
    Del(key interface{}) bool
}
```

And function returning singleton:

```
func Singleton() (cache *Cache) {
    if singleton != nil {
        return &singleton
    }
    //default
    singleton.(cache).lock.Lock()
    defer singleton.(cache).lock.Unlock()
    c := New(10000, WithTTL(10000 * 100))
    return &c
}
```

I am not sure which type should be my `singleton`:

1. When `var singleton cache` I cannot check for nil
2. If `var singleton Cache` I cannot cast to `singleton.(cache).lock.Lock()` O get error: `cache is not a type`

How to write goroutine-safe Singleton in Go in a correct way?

Comment: `cache is not a type` because its a return parameter of the function `...eton() (cache *Cache)...`, meaning in the scope of the `Singleton` function you don't have access to the type `cache` but to the variable `cache` of type `*Cache`.

Comment: Another problem, your logic is wrong, if singleton is *not nil* you return it, if it *is nil* you attempt type assertion on it, which will panic because it's nil. The type assertion itself doesn't have to panic, but the .lock.. part certainly will if singleton is nil.

Comment: Tip: It's not recommended to work with pointers to interface types, unless you have some peculiar requirements which make the pointer necessary. i.e. I would change `Singleton() *Cache` to `Singleton() Cache`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [sync.Once](https://godoc.org/sync#Once) to lazily initialize singleton values:

```
var (
    singleton Cache
    once      sync.Once
)

func Singleton() Cache {
    once.Do(func() {
        singleton = New(10000, WithTTL(10000*100))
    })
    return singleton
}
```

If it's OK to initialize at program startup, then do that:

```
var singleton Cache = New(10000, WithTTL(10000*100))

func Singleton() Cache {
    return singleton
}
```